# External @EJB injection return null with RESTeasy and JBoss

Tags: jboss, ejb, resteasy

I'm developing a RESTful Web Service on JBoss 6 Final with RESTeasy.
I have an external EJB and I want inject EJB on Web Service.

This is the code of EJB

BeanLocalInterface.java

```
@Local
public interface BeanLocalInterface {
  public String sayHello();
}
```

Bean.java

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "BeanLocal")
public class Bean implements BeanLocalInterface {

  @Override
  public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello!";
  }
}
```

In another project I have a WS:

```
@Path("/ws")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @EJB(mappedName="BeanLocal")
    private BeanLocalInterface bean;

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {            
        return bean.sayHello();
    }
}
```

MyRESTApplication.java

```
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    public MyRESTApplication(){
         singletons.add(new HelloWorldResource());
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
         return empty;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
         return singletons;
    }
}
```

bean is alwasy null!

I have tried this solution:

- I have put @Stateless on HelloWorldResources
- I have create beans.xml in WEB-INF
- I have change MyRESTApplication with

  @ApplicationPath("wsapp")
  public class MyRESTApplication extends Application { 
  }

Can you help me?

PS: I don't have EAR e I don't want use it

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Please tell me if you found a solution.

Comment: dear @Fabio Mignogna, I have the same problem, let me know how it solved...

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this. Firstly, remove all settings from web.xml regarding RESTeasy. You only need one adnotation --> @ApplicationPath

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {
//nothing required here, leave this empty

}
```

This is your session bean interface.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("MyEJB")
public interface BeanInterface {

@Path("{username}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayHello(@PathParam("username") String username);

}
```

This is your session bean.

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class EJB implements BeanInterface{

@Override
public String sayHello(String username) {

    return "Hello, "+username;
}

}
```

With JBOSS 7.1

Usage: http:// localhost:8080 /YOURAPPNAME/api/MyEJB/Fabio

Output:Hello, Fabio

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi adrian, thank you for response, but not solve my problem. I have a several EJB from my CRM and I want publish some web service for my iPad application. I resolve doing a lookup.

Comment: I am glad to have come across this answer. It has helped me to get CDI working in a RESTeasy service.  Can you explain why MyRESTApplication class contents is empty? It does work, but why does adding singletons here cause CDI to fail?

Comment: Dear @Adrian Stamin it does not work for me, please let me know if you have any other configuration in JBossEAP or Maven...